# Using Existing Role in CloudFormation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm trying to use an existing IAM role in a CFN template that is already being used by other services.

The `Resource` definition looks like this:

```
MyInstanceProfile:
  Type: "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile"
  Properties: 
    Path: "/"
    Roles: ["Capras999"]
```

And I'm referencing it like this:

```
LambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  Properties:
    Role: !Ref MyInstanceProfile
```

However I get this error:

`1 validation error detected: Value 'capras-cluster-Prsr-DL-with-params-MyInstanceProfile-1R68JNUXU0SAA' at 'role' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: arn:(aws[a-zA-Z-]*)?:iam::\d{12}:role/?[a-zA-Z_0-9+=,.@\-_/]+ (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 5f75a56d-8ce4-473e-924e-626a5d3aab0a)`

What am I doing wrong? Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For lambda function you need `role` not `instance-profile`.

The solution was to copy and paste an **existing role's ARN** into the template. Other possibility is to pass it in using a [parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html).

p.s.

Generally, you need to define [AWS::IAM::Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html) with a thrust policy for lambda. For example:

```
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
        RoleName: my-lambda-execution-role
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'               
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal: {'Service': ['lambda.amazonaws.com']}
              Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
        ManagedPolicyArns:
          - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaExecute
```

Then for your function you would do:

```
LambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  Properties:
    Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
```

Comment: can you please show me how to do that for an existing role?

Comment: @RedBottle Has this role been defined specifically for lambda function? You can't use role from an instance.

Comment: @RedBottle Is it defined in the same template or other template?

Comment: @RedBottle And you can't use its arn and just paste it in your template or pass it in using cfn parameter?

Comment: Ok trying that.

Comment: It worked pasting it directly. *Facepalm* Thank you. If u can please put this in the answer isntead. Let me accept it

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the instance name as the value, this parameter should instead be the Arn of the IAM role in question.

From your question you're trying to attach an instance profile to your Lambda, these are for EC2 instances only. Instead you want the Arn of the role itself.

From the console you can get the Arn for IAM role `Capras999`.

If you're using an existing role make sure to update your AssumeRolePolicy to also include `lambda.amazonaws.com` (and `lambdaedge.amazonaws.com` if using it for Lambda@Edge).

Comment: can you show me how to do that for an existing role please?

Comment: If you're wanting to use an existing IAM role, you can specify in your template as a CloudFormation Parameter: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html. By specifying it in your template you can then reference it by using the intrinsic function of `Ref`